# How can I use pandas.read_sql on an async connection?

Tags: pandas, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, orm, read-sql

I am trying to do the asynchron equivalent of

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///./test.db')
stmt = session.query(MyTable)
data = pd.read_sql(stmt, engine)
```

but it fails with the error `AttributeError: 'AsyncConnection' object has no attribute 'cursor'`.

What would be the right way to make this work?

```
asyn_engine = create_async_engine('sqlite+aiosqlite:///./test.db')
stmt = select(MyTable)
data = pd.read_sql(stmt, async_engine)
```

Answer (score 4):

This code in principal is working...

```
# Making pd.read_sql_query connection the first argument to make it compatible 
# with conn.run_syn()
def read_sql_query(con, stmt):
    return pd.read_sql(stmt, con)


async def get_df(stmt, engine):
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        data = await conn.run_sync(_read_sql, stmt)
    return data

asyn_engine = create_async_engine('sqlite+aiosqlite:///./test.db')
stmt = select(MyTable)

data = get_df(stmt, asyn_engine )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

`pd.read_sql` raise error with asyncpg, use `pd.read_sql_query` instead of that.